# How to tell that $W$ is a subspace of $ \mathbb R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: Is the set W a subspace of R3]

To do this problem, I wrote this matrix in RREF form and found that $V_3$ is $-1V_1 + 2V_2$. This demonstrates that these planes are a basis for $ \mathbb R^2$. However, I am not sure to extend that conclusion to show $ \mathbb R^2$ is a subspace of $ \mathbb R^3$. Any ideas how to prove this?

I think I need to demonstrate that it is closed under scalar multiplication and addition, and that it contains the zero vector, but I do not know how to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to understand that what you're looking at is the column space of 
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The column space is always going to be a subspace of the codomain, in this case $\mathbb{R}^3$. If you want to show this from first principles, you can, but you've almost done it already.

To show closure, take $v, w \in W$. We know there is some $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $Ax = v, Ay = w$. Thus, $A(cx+y) = cAx + Ay = cv + w$ for any scalar $c\in \mathbb{R}$.

That $0 \in W$ is clear: $A\cdot0 = 0$.

Comment: Just to be 100% clear, because the image is a subspace, the span of the columns of a matrix is always a subspace (as it is the image of the matrix) @Derek Allums

Comment: @ANB I would phrase it as: a matrix, after choosing a basis, represents a linear transformation from a vector space $V$ to a vector space $W$ and the image of a linear transformation, and thus the column space by definition, is a subspace of $W$.